# How to get the separate sheet in single workbook while combining multiple Excel workbook using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

my code :

```
Final_wb=pd.DataFrame()
 for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx):
   ws=pd.read(filename)
   Final_wb=pd.concat([Final_wb,ws],ignore_index=True)
 Final_wb.to_excel("Output.xlsx",index=False)
```

The above code works.But it combine all worbook into single workbook with single sheet.I need to read all workbook and combine into single workbook with multiple worksheets.(For Example, say i have 3 workbook with each workbook has each sheets so i can get single workboook[output.xlsx] with 3 sheets).I dont want to use xlsx writer and openpyxl. Share your knowledge on this..Anyone done this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont want to use xlsx writer and openpyxl

Not an option since you're using **xslx**. If you want to use the [xlwt](https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/) library then you have to change the file extension to *xsl*.

Assuming you did `import pandas as pd`:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("Output.xlsx", mode = 'a') as writer:
    for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
        ws = pd.read(filename)
        df = DataFrame(ws)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = filename.strip('.xlsx'), index = False)
```

If you do use the **XslxWriter** library, then when trying to do `pd.ExcelWriter("Output.xlsx", mode = 'a', engine = 'xlsxwriter')` you'll get an exception stating that this engine doesn't support append mode. But since the file is being closed after all the workbooks have been exported, it'll work in the default mode ('w') anyway. Example:

```
"""pip install pandas XslxWriter"""

import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter("Output.xlsx", mode = 'w', engine = 'xslxwriter') as writer:
    for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
        ws = pd.read(filename)
        df = DataFrame(ws)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = filename.strip('.xlsx'), index = False)
```

Comment: Is there any possible wihthout xlsx,Excelwriter,openpyxl & xlwt .........Only with the use of pandas.I am ok with xls & xlsx format

Comment: @PrasannaBalaji pandas doesn't have any logic to produce a valid XML file. It uses external libraries. When you install pandas via pip, it will install dependencies such as xlwt so you can use the DataFrame.to_excel method for example. If you want to produce xlsx files you need to install XlsxWriter or another library which can make valid Microsoft Excel files, then tell pandas to use that engine.

Comment: My name is with 'i'. I added an example in the answer for how to use xlsxwriter

Comment: Yes i got that...Sorry Iuri..